# Setting the data member for a class derived from a class derived from std::string to a value

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out this assignment from my level 2 class.
We are to create a class called Number, derived from std::string.
the only code in this class is to be two constructors, a default and one that takes a string as an arguement.
I have:

```
class Number : public string {
public:
    Number();
    Number(string set);
}
```

The constructors are then coded as:

```
Number::Number() : string("0") { } // default constructor sets data string to "0"
Number::Number(string set) : string(set) { }
```

So far so good. Then we are to take two classes that we have been developing, Double and Integer, and derive them from Number. Within these two classes we used to have a double and an int respectively as the data member. Now, because of inheritance, we are supposed to have a built in data section (string). The issue that I am having is that all of my operator=() overloads are now "recursive on all paths" leading to a stackoverflow at runtime. I will show an example of the Double constructor that takes a string, and the equals function that causes the infinite recursion.

```
Double::Double(string d) : Number(d)
{ 
    // overloaded constructor that takes a string argument
    if (isNaN(d)) {
        *this = "0.0";
    }
    else {
        *this = d;
    }

    // used for setting the value of a data member with a string
    void Double::operator=(string d) 
    {
        if (isNaN(d)) {
            *this = "0.0";
        }
        else {
            *this = d;
        }
    }
}
```

I see where the recursion is happening as *this is calling the overloaded = which calls itself since I am using *this in the = function itself. So what would the proper syntax be for setting the data member to a supplied value. Before it was just this->dataMemberName = supplied value of proper type.

It should be noted that my non-string constructors do set the value of an instanced object: 
`Double::Double(int d) : Number(to_string(d)){}` 
but the second I try to do anything with them, + - * /, the = function is called and then the error happens again.

Comment: It should be noted that my non-string constructors do set the value of an instanced object:
    Double::Double(int d) : Number(to_string(d)){} but the second I try to do anything with them, + - * /, the = function is called and then the error happens again.

Comment: If you want to add some info to your question, edit question. Do not use comments for adding information.

Comment: It's bad practice to derive from `std::string` or other standard containers, they're not designed for that. Normally you'd just have a member variable of `std::string` instead.

Comment: Totally understand that it is bad practice to derive from string. My own research has shown me that. it is required for this assignment though.

Comment: Still, seems like a _far_ better C++ class than most we see evidence of. So yay! FWIW this particularly exercise is a bit weird and you're doing quite well so far. Keep it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in comments I decided to rewrite my answer so that it is more clear what I mean.

You should just call the base class `operator=` and let it handle member assignment.

You have `class Number` defined like this:

```
class Number : public string {
public:
    Number();
    Number(string set);
};
```

Can this class work for us, as we want it without any modifications? Let's look.

> First thing we need is `operator=` in base class.

`operator=` is neither declared, nor `delete`d in class `Number` which means that if you call `Number& Number::operator=(Number const&)` this function will be generated for you by compiler. So we are good here.

> Second thing which is important for my solution to work is conversion from `std::string` to `Number`.

There is constructor `Number::Number(std::string)` in class `Number`. Fortunately it's not declared `explicit` co it can be used implicitly (with `explicit` constructor it would be more verbose, but also possible). Compiler will use this constructor when it needs to convert `std::string` into `Number`. One-parameter constructors are sometimes called *converting constructors*.
Ok, so we have second requirement fulfilled.

That's all we need from base class!

Now to work.

We begin with creation of a helper function:

```
std::string check_for_NaN(std::string s)
{
    if(isNaN(s)) { return "0.0"; }
    return s;
}
```

Now we can simplify `Double`'s constructor:

```
Double::Double(std::string s): Number(check_for_NaN(s)) //no magic here
{}
```

And we can create our long awaited `operator=` for class `Double`:

```
Double& operator=(std::string rhs)
{
    Number::operator=(check_for_NaN(rhs)); //here we have magic, explained below
    //if Double has some members of its own, copy them here
    return *this;
}
```

So, what happens when we call 'Number::operator=(check_for_NaN(rhs));'?

1. `check_for_NaN(rhs)` returns us proper string object.
2. Compiler looks for `Number::operator=(std::string)` but can't find it.
3. It finds that it can generatr `Number::operator=(const Number&)`!
4. Compiler checks it such an operator would help.
5. It would if we could convert `std::string` to `Number`.
6. But we can! There is `Number::Number(std::string)` constructor that is not explicit!
7. Compiler generates assignment operator.
8. From `std::string rhs` it creates a temporary object of class `Number`.
9. Calls generated operator.
10. We are all happy because it worked!

Comment: We aren't allowed to have any other code in the Number class other than the two constructors. The data member that we have to use is contained in std::string.

Comment: `operator=` is such a great (or very tricky, it depends) function that it frequently is created for us by compiler. Just use `Number`'s `operator=` in `Double`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add:

```
using std::string::operator=;
```

Abbreviated example:

```
#include <string>

class Number : public std::string {

public:

};

class Double : public Number {

public:

    using std::string::operator=;

    Double()
    {
        *this="0.0";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify directly that you want to use `std::string`'s `operator=`:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Number : public string
{
public:
    Number();
    Number(string set);
};


Number::Number() : string("0") {}//default constructor sets data string to "0"
Number::Number(string set) : string(set) {}

class Double : public Number {
public:
    //using Number::operator=;
    Double(string d);
    void operator=(string d);
    double val;
};

bool isNaN(string d) { return false; }

Double::Double(string d) : Number(d) {//overloaded constructor that takes a string argument
    if(isNaN(d))
    {
        string::operator=("0.0");
    }
    else
    {
        string::operator=(d);
    }
}

void Double::operator=(string d)//used for setting the value of a data member with a string
{

    if(isNaN(d))
    {
        string::operator=("0.0");
    }
    else
    {
        string::operator=(d);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Double d("3");
    d = "4";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Frankly speaking I would rather use `operator=` from direct base, not base of base. It's base's role to invoke `operator=` from base of base.

Comment: @Lehu Why? Wouldn't that just be a forwarding function in this case? Maybe if you're following a pimpl idiom? In any case OP has stated that he can only have constructors in `class Number`.

Comment: If `class Number` looks precisely like in the question the he will have `Number::operator=` generated for him by compiler.

Comment: In this case it's probably only function forwarding. But I'm speaking in wider perspective. Let's say that base class wants to do something before invoking it's base's `operator=`? Besides base class probably has its own data to copy. Then it should call `operator=` from BoB (base of base ;) ) regardless of derived class calling it or not. So if I call `BoB::operator=` from derived I'm calling it twice actually...

Comment: @Lehu *"If `class Number` looks precisely like in the question the he will have `Number::operator=` generated for him by compiler."* Are you sure the compiler will generate `Number::operator=`? I don't think it will be there unless you define it.

Comment: Yes,  I'm quite sure.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the suggestions. I will work on trying some of these out later on tonight. 
If I am understanding, it seems that the census is to call the Number::operator=() from within my derived classes' operator=() functions.

Comment: @Lehu Are you sure you're not confusing injected-class-name and name lookup for the compiler generating functions? Also, in this example using `Number::operator=("0.0");` would find `&Number::operator =(Number &&)` but [won't be able to use it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac34d46d08d0d09a).

Comment: @lehu, I ended up having to use base of base as the compiler kicked back that an instance of the overloaded operater= did not exist

Comment: @flatmouse Sure, Number::operator=(std::string) is not generated. Number::operator=(const Number&) is generated and I think it [should be used](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bcf0e76921f7184) .

Comment: @DRoc101 There is one more thing I should mention: my solution (see link in previous comment) takes advantage of the fact that constructor `Number::Number(std::string)` is not declared `explicit` and thus can be used to implicit conversion from `std::string` to `Number`.

Comment: @flatmouse I just thought about one more thing: what would happen if `Number`'s designer decided to change implementation so that it no longer inherited std::string and contain it instead (providing proper API of course)? Code calling `std::string::operator=` would stop working! If we use my approach, everything works fine. Of course my approach will also fail in some cases but I think that it's failures would be much fewer.

Comment: @Lehu True, that would be problem. I agree with the general approach you describe. These are toy programs and we are trying things (inheriting from `std::string`!) that we would not normally do.